# Changing UINavigationBar title in iOS8 Swift

Tags: uinavigationbar, swift, ios8

I have programmatically added UINavigationBar in my Superview called BaseViewController which inherits UIViewController. But When I try to set a title to the UINavigationBar. I get the error called **fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None**

Below is my swift class.
How can unwrap and change the UINavigationBar title

```
import UIKit

class BaseViewConroller: UIViewController {
    var navBar:UINavigationBar=UINavigationBar()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setNavBarToTheView()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        navBar.topItem.title="test test"
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func setNavBarToTheView()
    {
        navBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)
        navBar.backgroundColor=(UIColor .blackColor())
        self.view .addSubview(navBar)
    }

}
```

Comment: if the optional object is nil, you can not unwrap it. Thats why you get the error. 
Always validate objects for nil. 
As Rockey suggested try self.title

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Replace your `navBar.topItem.title="test test"` with `self.title="test test"`. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *labelTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero);
labelTitle.text = "Title";
labelTitle.text.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
self.navigationItem.titleView = labelTitle;
```

I've this code... I hope, that can help you.

Comment: fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None
Same error and prefer the swift code

Answer (score 0):

To change the navigation bar text pragmatically. Just call the func  `setNavigationBarTitleText("WhateverTextNeeded")` written below. I am assuming you already configured your UINavigationBar.

```
var navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectZero)

func setNavigationBarTitleText(text: String){
    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width - 120, 44))
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: UIConfig.Fonts.OswaldRegular,  size: 16)
    titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    titleLabel.text = text.uppercaseString
    self.navBar.topItem?.titleView = titleLabel
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to transform your navigation bar.

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "imageName")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "imageName")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = ""
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    self.title = "Title"
```